# Open an editing part(as an editor in previous eclipse versions) in Eclipse RCP 4

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I was wondering how could i open an e4 editor with an input(or an alternative to passing data from view) in a pure RCP 4 app.

If it helps, here is an app with all the things needed(except the actual editor)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zamn1t2kqr0525c/com.test.pureE4.zip?dl=0

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set data for the part in the transient data for the part.

Something like:

```
@Inject
EPartService partService;


// Create the part

MPart part = partService.createPart("editor id");

// Set the input

part.getTransientData().put("input key", inputData);

// Add to editor part stack

MPartStack editorStack = ... find your part stack for the editor

editorStack.getChildren().add(part);

// Show

partService.showPart(part, PartState.ACTIVATE);
```

In your editor code:

```
@Inject
MPart part;


inputData = part.getTransientData().get("input key");
```